# CentOS 7 Router/DHCP Server: Second NIC adapter plugged in but not sending internet through the cable

Tags: linux, networking, centos7, configuration

I have a CentOS 7 server configured as a router/dhcp server
There is two NICs installed in it - The first one is receiveing the internet from outside, and its working as it should be.

The second NIC is configured as a static IP and it should work as the router to forward internet to my notebook connected in it.

I configured dhcp.conf and also the network via nmtui
The problem is that the internet isnt being forwarded to my notebook, so it isnt working.
Can someone help me?

[image: NMTUI Configuration]

[image: DHCP Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable IP Forwarding in the kernel and net the firewall do NAT in the router. Just because you have two NICs, you machine does not "automagically" become a router

Let the kernel handle IP traffic:

```
vi /etc/sysctl_d/ip_forward.conf
```

and add the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

activate the change:

sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/ip_forward.conf

Next step is most likely to configure the firewall to allow IP masquerading between the public and private interfaces. Here `ens224` is the public interface and `10.73.0.0/24` is the private network.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens224 -j MASQUERADE -s 10.73.0.0/24
```

Don't forget to assign the interface to the external firewall zone:

```
firewall-cmd --change-interface=ens224 --zone=external --permanent
```

The Default zone should (most likely) be internal:

```
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=internal
```

Reload firewall's config

```
firewall-cmd --complete-reload
```

Restart all networking and firewall services:

```
systemctl restart network && systemctl restart firewalld
```

Verify the firewall settings:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=external
```

Set the internal's interface IP as the default gateway on your clients.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to do it using your information.